# How to understand failure cause from Android system recovery?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, recovery-mode, system-freeze

My phone stopped working(it freezes on Samsung logo when restarting) one day. I'm tring to figure out possible cause using Android system recovery.
That what I see

```
    MBR checksum Error
Moviinand Checksum Confirmation Fail
lfs pass open fail
update media
E: Can't mount /dev/block/mmblk0p1 (No such file)
E: copy_dbdata_demdia:Can't mount SDCARD
 your storage no prepared yet, please use UI menu for format and reboot
```

Formating/rebooting wipe data do not help me earthier.

What can cause such sitation?

Comment: What device are you referring to?

Comment: samsung GT-i9003

Comment: How did this happen? Are we missing details here?

Comment: Best take it back and get it checked out with your carrier as that's not a good thing for checksum failure  especially on MoviiNAND chip itself... hardware failure am guessing here... :(

Comment: It just stopped working without any reason overnight.

Comment: The MBR refers to near-equivalent of Windows's MBR aka Master Boot Record, but in the context of PBL(Primary BootLoader) or SBL (Secondary BootLoader) so its high probability that is hardware failure! Take it back to your carrier to get it replaced. Sorry, cannot do more! :(